# Red Black Tree ~ 1 Child Deletes

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, red-black-tree

Is it ever possible for a red parent node to have just ONE black child node? I have been playing around with the Red/Black Tree simulator online and I can't manage to get a case of this to happen.

The reason behind asking this is I believe I have an unnecessary IF in my code...

```
if (temp_node->color == BLACK && node->color == RED)
{
    node->color = BLACK;
    global_violation = false;
}
```

Thanks for any Feedback!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

Remember, that in a red/black tree, all paths from the root of the tree off of the tree must pass through the same number of black nodes (that's one of the red/black tree invariants).

If you have a red node `x` with one black child `y`, it cannot have another red child (since that breaks the red/black invariant that red nodes can't have red children).

This means that a path through `x` to the missing child will pass through at least one fewer black node than the path through `x`, then to `y`, and then off the tree from there, breaking the red/black tree invariants.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

There is currently (oct,2021) at least on diagram in Wikipedia that has one black node.

If this is a confusion, it could be helpful to explicitly rule out the  one-node cases as a new rule.